# IOS Switch between views

Tags: ios, view, rootview

I have ios project with storyboard. There are 4 views in storyboard. The first view that come after navigation controller is "Login View". In all other views there is a Logout button.
When you click the button I want the application show the Login View. But I could not find how to do this.

Please can you show me the code how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the view controllers connected and pushed onto each other?

Comment: Yes, they are connected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tutorial shows you how to go back and forth between 2 different views in storyboard, you should be able to apply it to your problem.

http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/using-storyboards-to-create-a-single-view-application/1363/